# Prevent hsqldb to stop on error when initializing the database

Tags: spring, hsqldb, spring-test

For testing my application I wrotte a special application-context-test.xml
I want use an internal hsqldb as data source like this :

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" >   
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/init.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/testData.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

the init.sql is generated by hibernate3-maven-plugin and start with some drop constraint and table like this :

```
alter table t_menu 
        drop constraint fk_menu_menu;
```

So when the init.sql is loaded it fails of course with the error :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table not found: T_MENU in statement [alter table t_menu]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
```

I could make a special initTest.sql script with no drop, but I would have to keep it up to date manually each time the schema change.

Is there any option to tell hsql to keep executing the script on error ?

thanks !

Comment: So your letting hibernate autogenerate the DDL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Hibernate is auto generating the DDL why not just remove the script:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" >   
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/testData.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Comment: aw it is now working because it tries to execute the script before hibernate create the table :(. I need another way to initialize my db

Answer (score 3):

For my initial question I found a way to ignore failure like this :

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" ignore-failures="ALL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/init.sql"/>    
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/testData.sql"/>

</jdbc:initialize-database>

<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
```